# Get a specific object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here is the sample input

```
const arr = [{name:'bruce', surname: 'wayne'}, {name:'clark', surname:'kent'}]
```

How to get an output that would be like

```
result = {bruce:'wayne', clark:'kent'}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.reduce()` like so:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "bruce", surname: "wayne"},
  {name: "clark", surname: "kent"}
];

const result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr.name]: curr.surname}),
  {}
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a new object with key that equals to name and value that equals to surname.

```js
const arr = [{name:'bruce', surname: 'wayne'}, {name:'clark', surname:'kent'}]

const completeNameArrObj =  arr.map(item => ({[item.name]:item.surname}));

console.info(completeNameArrObj);
```

Comment: That's still an array of objects. Asker's requested output is a single object.

Comment: dude, whats the filter criteria? names can be dyanmic. the answer was just to give an idea not to spoonfeed

Comment: Don't worry this question is cursed. My answer (that fully matches the expected output) got destroyed too.